# Joomla 2.5: You do not have access to the administrator section of this site

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla, joomla2.5

I have trouble with my Joomla 2.5
I see this when i'm login with correct superuser username and password

[image: error message]

I also included SQL file if you want to analyze it
here is: http://akdira.drivehq.com/akdira/u889932813_ah2.sql

Can someone give solution please?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue a few days ago & was lost in finding an answer.

However, I did find this website: http://www.itoctopus.com/you-do-not-have-access-to-the-administrator-section-of-this-site-error-when-trying-to-login-to-joomlas-admin & in that had my answer.

The section that helped me was in step 3.

> Step 3: Check the jos_assets table: If all else fails, then (sadly)
>   the problem almost certainly lies in the jos_assets table (which is,
>   by far, the scariest table in Joomla – because a simple mistake in
>   that table can cause a total collapse of the website). The two most
>   common causes in the jos_assets table that might lead to this problem
>   are:
>
> Missing entry for the com_admin row. (By the way, that was the reason why the system administrator at that chip maker company wasn’t able to login to the website)
>
> Wrong rules field for the com_admin row. The rules field for that row should just contain “{}”. (two curly brackets)

I found in my site that the first three entries were deleted from the assets table.

I suggest you look at your assets table & compare it to a clean site & add in any that are missing. T

Comment: This question is targeted for Joomla 2.5, while the post explains it mostly for 1.5.

Comment: I personally don't believe it is, my website was also a Joomla 2.5 website that had the issue and it fixed my problem.

Plus the fact is, in the post they reference the assets & viewlevels tables which weren't in Joomla 1.5.

So, I'm fairly sure the blog post was related to Joomla 2.5.

Comment: You are right. The `jos_..` prefix they use, made me think it wasn't.

Comment: This actually happened to me again today, I'm so glad I wrote this comment, I would've forgotten it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is your problem, but you can try to run the following query:

```
UDPATE `ah2_users` SET `password` = "d2064d358136996bd22421584a7cb33e:trd7TvKHx6dMeoMmBVxYmg0vuXEA4199"
  WHERE `username` = "akdira"
```

This will try to reset the password for user with username `akdira`.
The new password should be the word`secret`

Note to all readers: The table `ah2_users` is just for this site. The prefix will probably be different for other sites.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your #_assets table has parent_id=0 for Root Asset. If not, set parent_id=0 for root asset. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with joomla 3.9, Checked and found #__user_usergroup_map table has the wrong mapped for admin. I have changed role_id to 8, It works!

Comment: If you are using Joomla, please make contributions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange -- a dedicated Stack Exchange community specifically designed to cater to Joomla-related questions.